# How do I handle situations when I need to use personal software for a commercial purpose?

Tags: licensing, ide

If I work for a company and write code for them but I choose to buy a tool for myself and use it to write code for the company, do I need a commercial or personal license?

Specifically, in this case, I am asking about [WebStorm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/)

JetBrains have Commercial (For companies and organizations) and Personal (For individual developers). I am an individual developer working for a company!

Comment: The [License Comparison Chart](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/license-matrix.jsp) is quite clear about it, even without using legal jargon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot provide customer support for any company. For questions about their products, pricing, and licenses, please contact the official customer support directly.

Comment: https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207240855-Can-I-use-my-personal-license-at-work-and-at-home-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Jetbrains, the corporate license is a license that's not linked to an individual. The personal license is linked to a specific person.
What that means inside a company is that if you buy a corporate license for 10 users, any 10 people can use the product at any given time.
If however you buy 10 personal licenses, only the 10 specific people who are mentioned can ever use the product. Were one of them to leave the company, that license becomes useless (though they might have a means to get the license transfered to another person, you'd have to contact Jetbrains about that). If one of them is on a 6 months long sabatical, there will thus be only 9 licenses in use as a maximum. With a corporate license you could get a contractor or intern to take over for 6 months and reuse that license.

As you're buying yourself for use at work (and probably at home as well) you'd purchase a personal license. That will allow you and only you to use it on any number of computers (but only on one computer at a time, if memory serves (it's been a few years since I read the fine print, and that specific wasn't relevant to me at the time as I only had one computer per location).

Comment: The jet brains personal license can also only be bought by the individual and getting reimbursed by the company is a violation of the license.

Comment: @user40980 So imagine that company doesn't want to buy license but I want to buy personal license for me and use it on work. Is that possible?

Comment: @svlada yes, you can use your personal license for any purpose, including at work. And no, your employer can reimburse your purchase as long as they then don't become owner of the license. For example if you have a "budget for personal items" that you're free to use and what you buy from it becomes your propert, you can use that budget to cover the license fee. If you have to hand over to the company whatever you bought from the budget, you can't use it.

Comment: Are you sure that employer can reimburse for purchase because this is strictly forbidden by EULA => https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/206544499-Can-a-company-reimburse-my-personal-license-purchase-

Comment: @svlada the scenario I represent is no different from buying the license from your salary, except for accounting purposes it's a different bucket of money for the company. The license is in your name, remains in your name, and is purchased by you. The license is never transfered, never becomes property of the company. THAT would be a violation. or you'd have to read the EULA as stating that a personal license can't be used for development you do for your employer, which would likely mean the vast majority of personal licenses are used in violation of the EULA.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to address not the legal issue but whether it is a good idea at all. In other words the impact on the company of you choosing to have a personal license.

If the product is something that makes your work easier but does not affect the ability of others in your company to maintain the same code, a personal license may be a good idea provided your company has no problem with you having it on your work computer (some companies especially ones with a large IT team tend to be very picky about what can be put on a computer for "security" reasons.)

However, if the code cannot be maintained except through using this tool, then you really need to have a corporate license that can move easily to another person when you are no longer there. You also should not be using such a tool without the knowledge and agreement of your company. For instance suppose you were tasked to develop some reports and your company has SQL Server which has its own reporting tool, but you personally prefer Crystal Reports so you use your personal copy of it to develop the reports. That would be unacceptable. But if you wanted to use a tool to format the code easily to meet a certain coding standard, the code is still usable by others, so it is OK.

Comment: Thanks for making this point. In this case, it's web development. Using this tool will not affect someone maintaining the code as there are a plethora of tools to code and maintain web apps (html, css & js).

Comment: I was also thinking about pointing this out for future readers, I was pretty sure the tool you wanted to use would be fine, but I have seen some messes created where people did something in a tool that the company didn't have and then left.

Comment: Even in that case, get approval from someone in a position to approve, before using any non-corporately supplied software.  Where I currently work, there's agreement that open-source licenced software can be used but personal licences are out, even for IDEs - thankfully, even though I can't use my IntelliJ personal license, these days I can at least use the community edition!